# Arguing away/bounding an integral in contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

basically I have a contour integration problem where I am trying to determine the value of
 $$\int \frac {(z^2-1)^{1/2}} {(z^2+1)} dz$$ around a dumbbell contour. I am computing this integral with the ultimate aim of finding  $$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac {(1-x^2)^{1/2}} {(x^2+1)} dx$$

In my problem I need to "argue away" the components of my integral around two circles of small radius approaching zero, i.e. show these components tend to $0$ as the radius tends to $0$

We have on a circle $\gamma$ of radius $\epsilon$ centred at 1

$$\vert \int \frac {(z^2-1)^{1/2}} {(z^2+1)} dz \vert \le 2\pi\epsilon .\max \vert \frac {(z^2-1)^{1/2}} {(z^2+1)} \vert$$

It is the $\epsilon\max \vert \frac {(z^2-1)^{1/2}} {(z^2+1)} \vert = \epsilon\frac {\max \vert (z^2-1)^{1/2} \vert}{\min \vert z^2+1 \vert}$ on $\gamma$ that I'm struggling to find. I need to show this is of order $\epsilon$ to a positive power and hence as $\epsilon \to 0$ so too does the integral. I was wondering if anyone could help?

Comment: Look at the centre $c$ of the circle. What does $z^2+1$ converge to as $z\to c$, and what does $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ converge to?

Comment: apologies, the circle is centred at 1. Why do we consider the value of z as it approaches c when we are trying to find the maximum value of f(z) on the circle?

Comment: We don't need the precise maximum of $\lvert f(z)\rvert$ on the circle. A not too bad upper bound for it suffices.

Comment: In this case then is it not possible to find the precise maximum, or at least find the bound in a way that we have a specific order of epsilon?

Comment: We can find the precise maximum, it's just not worth the effort. It suffices to see that the integrand is uniformly bounded for $0 < \varepsilon \leqslant 1/2$, say.

Comment: alright thanks, its just that in the problem itself I have been asked to show that it is order of a positive power of epsilon, and I can't seem to get such a result.

Comment: If you just use that $\dfrac{\sqrt{z^2-1}}{z^2+1}$ is bounded near $1$, you get (a constant times) $\varepsilon^1$. If you are less generous, note that for $\lvert z-1\rvert = \varepsilon$ one has $\lvert \sqrt{z^2-1}\rvert \sim \sqrt{2\varepsilon}$, so together with $z^2+1 \to 2$, one gets the power $\varepsilon^{3/2}$.

Comment: Ah I see now, thanks very much for your help

Answer (score -1):

You have to imagine that, attached to your dumbbell is a circle of radius $R$ centered at the origin.  Thus, letting all of the radii of the small detours about $z=\pm1$ go to zero, the contour integral is equal to

$$\oint_C dz \frac{(z^2-1)^{1/2}}{z^2+1} = i 2 \int_{-1}^1 dx \frac{(1-x^2)^{1/2}}{1+x^2} + i R \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{(R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}-1)^{1/2}}{R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}+1}$$

As $R \to \infty$, the latter integral about the big circle approaches $i 2 \pi$.

By the residue theorem, the contour integral is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues at the poles of the integrand at $z=\pm i$.  Thus,

$$i 2 \int_{-1}^1 dx \frac{(1-x^2)^{1/2}}{1+x^2} + i 2 \pi = i 2 \pi \left (\frac{\sqrt{2} e^{i \pi/2}}{2 e^{i \pi/2}} + \frac{\sqrt{2} e^{-i \pi/2}}{2 e^{-i \pi/2}} \right )$$

or,

> $$\int_{-1}^1 dx \frac{(1-x^2)^{1/2}}{1+x^2} = (\sqrt{2}-1) \pi$$

**ADDENDUM**

In my haste I did not see that the OP's concern is those small circles.  Consider $z=-1$.  Above the real axis, we parametrize by $z=e^{i \pi}+\epsilon \, e^{i \phi}$ and have the contribution to the contour integral being

$$i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{(2 e^{i \pi} \epsilon e^{i \phi})^{1/2}}{2} $$

which vanishes as $\epsilon \to 0$.  Same goes below the axis.  Similar analysis for $z=-1$, except we only need one integral from $\pi$ to $-\pi$.

Comment: in terms of determining the value of the integral for the big circle, can we consider our function/integrand when z is large (i.e. ignoring the +1 in the denominator), and use laurent series to compute the residue?

Comment: @Duncan: if I understand you right, then yes, that is precisely what is done.

Comment: When doing this I have 1/z + g(z) where g(z) is of order O(z^-3). Therefore for large z we can read off the residue as 1, hence giving the integral as 2i(pi) as you have above?